# How to add library to Vert.x's FatJar?

Tags: java, vert.x

I am building an app using Vert.x Ver. 2.1M6. And I'm using Vert.x's FatJar feature to have the app be portable. My question is...how do I add additional libraries to the lib folder that Vert.x creates upon running the FatJar?

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to create a FatJar is to use maven shade plugin.

here is the sample of how it can be used.

http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/